# Self-reference in function definition

Tags: scope, scheme, lisp, sicp, y-combinator

In this explanation of Y-combinator (https://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html),

```
  (define almost-factorial
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (n)
        (if (= n 0)
            1
            (* n (f (- n 1)))))))


  (define factorialA (almost-factorial factorialA))
```

it says that the definition of factorialA would go into an infinite loop in standard scheme, however implementing it gives an error saying factorial A isn't defined.

I think this is expected as when we are defining (if not with a lambda) we are evaluating the definition which will end up calculating the arguments, one of which is the same function not yet defined.

Is this correct and how can we explain the above article then?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the expression `(define p M)`, where `M` is some expression and `p` is a variable.

Let's suppose we're evaluating this expression in environment `E`. Evaluating `(define p M)` should do two things:

1. It should evaluate `M` in environment `E`; let the result be `x`.
2. It should modify environment `E` so that `p` is bound to `x`.

So what should happen when we evaluate `(define factorialA (almost-factorial factorialA))` in an environment `E` where `factorialA` is not already defined?

First, we try to evaluate `(almost-factorial factorialA)` in environment `E`. To do this, we first evaluate `almost-factorial`, which succeeds. We then evaluate `factorialA`, which fails because `factorialA` is not defined in environment `E`. Thus, the whole thing should be expected to fail.

On the other hand, if we try

```lisp
(define (returns-factorialA) (almost-factorial (returns-factorialA)))
(define factorialA (returns-factorialA))
```

This does indeed run into an infinite loop. This is probably what the writer of the article was looking for.

Comment: I think `almost-factorial` can't be 'evaluated' separately as it is a function taking `factorialA` as argument, just that since in the definition `factorialA` is encountered , we cannot find it as it's not defined yet.

Comment: @user10206517 You're confusing evaluating with applying. To evaluate an expression of the form `(f x)`, we first evaluate `f`, then evaluate `x`, and finally apply `f` to `x`. Functions must be evaluated too - we could have a situation like `((if (= a b) (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) (lambda (x) (+ 2 x))) 2)`.

Comment: Sorry, how did the second thing work , it also refers to (returns-factorialA) which wasn't defined. Also why the extra bracket around what is being defined in the first case?

Comment: The second definition is equivalent to `(define returns-factorialA (lambda () (almost-factorial (returns-factorialA))))`. We're defining `returns-factorialA` to be a 0-input function that's supposed to return `factorialA`. In this second case, we go into an infinite loop when we try to call `returns-factorialA`.

Answer (score 0):

From the SICP perspective, this is not a self-referencing procedure because factorialA is a value, not procedure.

in Chapter 4 [Representing Expressions](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.2) which develops a scheme evaluator we have:

```
(define (definition-value exp)
  (if (symbol? (cadr exp))
      (caddr exp)
      (make-lambda (cdadr exp)   ; formal parameters
                   (cddr exp)))) ; body
```

What this means is that if the expression after `define` is a raw symbol like `factorialA` then it will evaluate the body of the expression immediately and assign its value to `factorialA`.  But if it is a list like `(factorialA)` or `(factorialA n)` then it will create a lambda expression instead.  When the lambda expression is evaluated a procedure is created meaning the body is only evaluated when the procedure is called.