# SICP recursive let definition

Tags: scope, scheme, let, sicp

For

```
(let ((fact 
        (lambda (n)
            (if (= n 1)
                1
                (* n (fact (- n 1)))))))
(fact 10))
```

Scheme gives an error, i wanted to *confirm if my reasoning is correct,*

Since `(let ((var1 arg1)) body)` is equivalent to evaluating the body in an environment where `var1` is bound to `arg1`.

Above, when we are trying to calculate `arg1` before the bind call, we do not find the reference as that is exactly what we are trying to bind for it to be available

But then why does this not throw

```
(let ((fact (lambda (n) 
             (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (fact (- n 1))))))) 
  (display 10))
```

as we are trying to make the binding there as well.

Also why doesn't this throw then

```
(define factorial
    (lambda (n)
      (if (= n 0)
          1
          (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
          
(factorial 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the "variable fact is not bound" error occurs only when we actually try to look up the value of "fact". Consider

```lisp
(let ((fact (lambda (n) (if (= n 0)
                            1
                            (* n (fact (- n 1)))))))
 (fact 0))
```

This does not cause an error because we do not enter the `else` clause and therefore do not attempt to use the value of the unbound variable `fact`. However, trying the same thing with `1` does give us the error.

We do not run into an error when using `define` because `define` and `let` have different rules. In a `let` binding, you create a new lexical scope, and the binding of `fact` in the `let` binding does not "leak out" from the `let` to the outside world. Since the right side of a `let` assignment must only refer to bindings from the outside world, the right side cannot refer to the binding `fact`.

However, in a `define` statement, the whole point is to introduce a new binding in the current scope (not create a new scope). In a `define` binding, the right side of the assignment must refer only to variables from the outside world - but this potentially includes the variable being `define`d, as long as accessing it is hidden behind a `lambda` and hence done lazily.

In fact, consider the following:

```lisp
(define is-even
  (lambda (n) (or (= n 0)
                  (is-odd (- n 1)))))

(define is-odd
  (lambda (n) (and (not (= n 0))
                   (is-even (- n 1)))))

(display (is-odd 55))
```

In this case, by the time we actually call `is-even`, `is-odd` is `define`d in the same scope as `is-even` and hence we can look up its value. Similarly, when we call `is-odd`, `is-even` is already defined and hence we have a binding for its value.

Note that the following does *not* work:

```lisp
(define is-even
  (lambda (n) (or (= n 0)
                  (is-odd (- n 1)))))

(display (let ((is-odd (lambda (n) (and (not (= n 0))
                                        (is-even (- n 1))))))
            (is-odd 55)))
```

This is because the `is-odd` binding here is *not* in the same scope as `is-even`. It is defined in a more local binding than `is-even` is. The `is-odd` being referred to in the `is-even` definition cannot be the same `is-odd` as created in the `let` statement, because this `is-odd` is a local binding and thus cannot be referred to in the wider scope that `is-even` is defined in.

If we were using the old-fashioned LISP notion of "dynamic scope", also known as "call-by-name semantics", the latter example would work perfectly fine. However, Scheme does not support dynamic scope (which is definitely for the best in my view).

Comment: Thanks, just one followup - if we are using let with a variable like `let a 3` vs if it's with a function `let fact lambda(n) (..)` is there a difference in the time the binding is made. Is the binding in the second function made only when fact is called? If not then even `(let (fact lambda(b) (..)) (fact 0)` should have thrown an error. It sounds weird for `let` to make a binding on function call. (for let what they say is it first makes the binding and then evaluates its body with that binding). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user10206517 No, it doesn't throw an error because the error only occurs when we attempt to access the value of an unbound variable, *not* when we define a function with an unbound variable in it.  Your example is actually even less extreme than my initial example with `(fact 0)` - we can compute `(fact 0)` just fine because computing `(fact 0)` doesn't hit the bad branch of the `if` statement which causes the error. In the `(display 8)` case, we don't even call `fact` at all and are therefore at no risk of running into an unbound variable.

Comment: Is let being bound after the function call? the call is in let's body, so shouldn't let first make the binding of `fact` before invoking the body. eg. if it were (let (a 2) (display (+ a 2)) , a would be bound to 2 and then the body is executed. If similar thing happens then fact would already be bound when it's referred and hence be defined

Comment: Or are you saying that it is bound just that , when it tries to evaluate the lambda it cannot find `fact` as it's only looking in outside environments, not in the current environment where it would find it of course

Comment: @user10206517 Yes. `fact` is indeed defined when we do the `(let (fact (lambda ...)) (fact 0))` example - otherwise, we wouldn't be able to calculate `(fact 0)` at all. But it is defined in the new environment created by the `let` statement. The value `(lambda (n) (if (= n 0) ...))` creates a procedure which, when evaluated, uses the *old* environment that does not include `fact`. On the other hand, the procedure created by the `define` statement uses the current environment, which the `define` statement modifies by adding the binding of `fact`.

Comment: Thanks, you can also possibly answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862564/self-reference-in-function-definition, which is closely related